# grep, awk - output every first line

Tags: awk, grep

I have several thousand links to the image, of different sizes. Each first link has the largest image size. They look like this:

```
https://userapi.com/c84472122/v844721232/143ffc/4Sgsfsf-EyA.jpg
https://userapi.com/c84472122/v844721232/143ffb/IdLDJU4usI8.jpg
https://userapi.com/c84612122/v846121642/13684b/jq5FRWnwzIY.jpg
https://userapi.com/c84612122/v846121642/13684a/wmKy022Qaik.jpg
https://userapi.com/c84612122/v846121642/136849/IZQrSossuMw.jpg
https://userapi.com/c85043622/v850436595/4df71/7y7qHUotpuI.jpg
https://userapi.com/c85043622/v850436595/4df70/nowGp0MVeO0.jpg
https://userapi.com/c85043622/v850436595/4df6f/HnkYnd2WQ_s.jpg
https://userapi.com/c84913622/v849136355/bd12b/sqyYycXM9ug.jpg
https://userapi.com/c84913622/v849136355/bd12a/7uqIIMykk50.jpg
https://userapi.com/c84913622/v849136355/bd129/f_XDzdpgH_g.jpg
https://userapi.com/c85003222/v850032096/b93df/xkQGlX6d6Ek.jpg
https://userapi.com/c85003222/v850032096/b93de/CWhHXRm99Lw.jpg
https://userapi.com/c85003222/v850032096/b93dd/RxBudOclDo0.jpg
```

So, I don’t need the biggest images. I need to leave only every first link. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
grep -m 1 “c84472122\c84612122\c85043622\c84913622\c85003222” file.txt
```

But I gave an error

Comment: Maybe `head -1 file.txt`?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what's "each first link"? What's "the image"? Notice that your grep command uses "smart quotes" (`“` instead of `"`), which grep will look for literally (and not find them).

Answer (score 1):

The image is located in the 4th and 5th field reference when the delimiter is a <forward-slash>. The following line compares these fields and prints if one of them is different.

```
$ awk -F/ '($4!=a || $5!=b) { print; a=$4; b=$5 }' file
```

This outputs:

```
https://userapi.com/c84472122/v844721232/143ffc/4Sgsfsf-EyA.jpg
https://userapi.com/c84612122/v846121642/13684b/jq5FRWnwzIY.jpg
https://userapi.com/c85043622/v850436595/4df71/7y7qHUotpuI.jpg
https://userapi.com/c84913622/v849136355/bd12b/sqyYycXM9ug.jpg
https://userapi.com/c85003222/v850032096/b93df/xkQGlX6d6Ek.jpg
```